# Detecting if key is pressed objective-c++

Tags: c++, macos, objective-c++, core-foundation

Without using Cocoa, how could I detect if a key is currently pressed in objective-c++? In Windows you use 'GetAsyncKeyState'.

Comment: What kind of application is this?  Objective-C++ is a programming language, and as such provides no keyboard access at all.  Neither does Core Foundation.

Comment: I'm creating a command line application in Xcode.

Comment: I don't know enough about any of these to make this an answer, but look into the ncurses library and the lower-level terminfo and/or termcap libraries. And, of course, your program should do something reasonable whenever it is run without a terminal—e.g., by a cron job, launchd job, or GUI process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible.  Command line programs interact with input and output files (`stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`), which do not transmit events such as "key pressed" or "key released", but only streams of characters (bytes, actually).